# Error en consulta con fechas y collations charset - illegal mix of collations

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo toda mi BD MySQL, tablas y columnas con el `charset utf8` y `collation utf8_spanish_ci`

Cuándo ejecuto ésta consulta:

```
SELECT * 
FROM profesionales INNER JOIN horarios
ON profesionales.id = horarios.idProfesional
WHERE horarios.idDia = 3
AND horarios.desde <= '09:00:00'
AND '09:00:00' <= (TIMEDIFF(horarios.hasta, '01:00:00'))
GROUP BY horarios.id
```

me devuelve le siguiente error:

```
Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '<='
```

Estoy pensando en que puede ser la forma en la cual tengo mis horas (horarios.desde y horarios.hasta son de tipo TIME, en MySQL) y la que le paso y me devuelve la función `TIMEDIFF()`, no se si es con comillas simples o dobles, o sin los segundos, o no sé...

Comment: Podrías detallar un poco sobre que es lo que deseas obtener con aquella consulta, ya que el uso del TIMEDIFF pareciera demás.

Comment: El mensaje es claro:la `collation`  de algunas de tus tablas están en conflicto. Convendría que unifiques, si es posible. Si no es posible, en la consulta debes salvar la compatibilidad dando temporalmente a una u otra tabla una collation compatible con la otra. Debes revisar bien porque esto no es cierto: *Tengo toda mi BD MySQL, tablas y columnas con el charset utf8 y collation utf8_spanish_ci*.  El mensaje de error te contradice: indica que en alguna tabla/columna tienes `latin1_swedish_ci`. Con un `SHOW CREATE TABLE nombre-tabla` verás el estado real de cada tabla y de sus columnas.

Comment: El charset de la base de datos y del motor son distintos o haces un cast o migra la base de datos